# Is there a Plasma shared knowledge space?

Tags: plasma

And maybe somewhere one can follow the implementers shared knowledge space?

Thanks

Comment: Spotted a typo: here's the link again :-) https://ethresear.ch/t/minimal-viable-plasma/426

Answer (score 0):

There is the plasma implementer call videos, including number of teams that are implementing the mvp, that is being uploaded.[Please find it here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCG2MeKuKDJRK4gFNk-dQuZQ/videos)